# Jquery Not Sending the Form to HTTP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some problems with Jquery/Ajax.

This is my code for the form :

```
<form class="form-auth-small" method="POST" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="signin-email" class="control-label sr-only">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="samuel.gold@domain.com" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="signin-email" class="control-label sr-only">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="John">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="signin-email" class="control-label sr-only">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="938434928">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="signin-email" class="control-label sr-only"></label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="****">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="image" type="file" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Register</button>
</form>
```

And this is my code to AJAX/Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(".submit").on("click", function(e) {
        var form = $("#form");
        // you can't pass Jquery form it has to be javascript form object var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/user/signup/',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false, //this is requireded please see answers above       processData: false, //this is requireded please see answers above       //cache: false, //not sure but works for me without this        error: function (err) {             console.log(err);
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

When i do console.log to check that from form i don't receive any value, and when i check in network i dont see any HTTP callback.

Comment: There is (was) an orphan closing curly brace at the end.

Comment: So you expect all users to press the button instead of pressing the `enter` key?

Comment: Yes but don't work @RonvanderHeijden

Comment: It's sending the call for http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup, don't know why

Comment: Your problem is button`type=submit` lets the browser handle the submit.  You don't want the browser to submit as you're submitting via ajax.  So change the button type to `type=button` so that the browser doesn't also submit.  Then you just need to hook the submit function in correctly by using ID (as others have pointed out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you were using the `class` selector token `.` (dot) instead of the `id` selector token `#` hashtag. Further details can be found on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Change this instruction

```
$(".submit").on("click", function(e) // …
```

to

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e) // …
```

Comment: Please give more details on why the code did not work. The author may not be aware of differences between `id` and `class` attributes/selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have submit class. You have id="submit"

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
```

Use this and it should work.

Also change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` or in your js code you need to add

```
e.preventDefault();
```